# Assist with understanding Shada"l regarding grammatic usage in Shemot 18:26

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hebrew, grammar-dikduk, parashas-yisro, shadal

Exodus 18:26 (minor modif. to Sefaria English):

> וְשָׁפְט֥וּ אֶת־הָעָ֖ם בְּכָל־עֵ֑ת אֶת־הַדָּבָ֤ר הַקָּשֶׁה֙ יְבִיא֣וּן
>   אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֔ה וְכָל־הַדָּבָ֥ר הַקָּטֹ֖ן **יִשְׁפּוּט֥וּ** הֵֽם׃
>
> And they judged the people at all times: the hard matters they brought
>   to Moses, and every small matter they judged themselves.

I was curious about the "strange" usage of the verb יִשְׁפּוּט֥וּ using the *shuruq*. I find an explanation  by [Shada"l](http://www.sefaria.org/Shadal_on_Exodus.18.26?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all), but I don't really understand what he's saying.

I'd appreciate if someone can summarize the main points. I don't need a literal translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shadal quotes ibn Ezra's explanation that this is a pausal form. This is the case even though the word is not the last in the verse: because the last word, 'הֵֽם', is a very short word, it somehow doesn't count as a separation between יִשְׁפּוּט֥וּ and the end of the verse. This case also differs from regular pausal usage in that the long vowel that is put in is a shuruk: one would expect the non-pausal form 'yishpetu' to become 'yishpotu', with a holam.

(A pausal form is a form that a word takes when it occurs at the end of a verse or at the end of a phrase, i.e., a place where a reader would pause slightly. Usually the change that occurs is that a short vowel becomes a long vowel, for example 'יכתבו / yikhtevu' becoming 'יכתובו / yikhtovu'.)

Shadal then goes on to disagree with ibn Ezra's application of this explanation to a few other specific instances in the Bible of verbs getting an unusual long vowel. I think that Shadal accepts ibn Ezra's explanation here, though, and lets that stand as the answer to the question of the unusual form of יִשְׁפּוּט֥וּ.

Comment: Yes. This helps, thanks. If you or anyone knows why this grammatical rule is there or some place where I can learn more about this, I'd appreciate it. This is, apparently, some nuance in Biblical grammar that "Modern" Hebrew doesn't follow, and I don't know how consistent even this rule is in the Bible, either.

Comment: @DanF In his *Sefer Tzahut* (linked below), Ibn Ezra gives the example of "יכסימו" from Shirat HaYam. Also the *perush* there explains that even though there's a "הם" as mentioned, the *ta'am* is continuous (*mercha*).
https://books.google.co.il/books?id=VrUSP16x1j0C&pg=PT60&lpg=PT60&dq=%22%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%98%D7%95+%D7%94%D7%9D%22&source=bl&ots=qMLh_dQs_u&sig=Z0sr7xD0UPRlcbt-4eHIKNtv8Kc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBk7TOssrKAhUGOQ8KHWN9AX0Q6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=%22%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%98%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%9D%22&f=false

Comment: I just realized that another anomaly here is that the accent is still on the last syllable and doesn't shift back one syllable. The accent shifting back is usually a key characteristic of pausal forms.

Comment: There's yet another anomaly, and this one REALLY makes Shadal's analysis strange... I assume that the "pausal form" would include an etnachta. If so, we should expect the same format in verse 22. Unless he is specifically referring to a mercha before the etnachta, which does not occur in verse 22.